# Using predict() with a vector of specific values in lapply for a list of data.frames

Tags: r

I am trying to achieve the following. I have a list of dataframes in the form of:

```
list1 <- list(d1=data.frame(name=rep("d1",3), A=c(1,2,3), B=c(2,4,5)),
              d2=data.frame(name=rep("d2",3), A=c(1,2,3), B=c(2,4,5)),
              d3=data.frame(name=rep("d3",3), A=c(1,2,3), B=c(2,4,5)))
```

For each dataframe in `list1`, i want to fit a linear model and then use this model for `predict()`. The values to use for predictions are in a separate dataframe:

```
new.values <- data.frame(name=c("d1","d2","d3"), B=c(3,4,5))
```

Each model shall be used with only one value from `new.values`, the one with the corresponding name (e.g. for `list$d1` the value in `new.values[new.values$name == d1, ]`), not for all values in `new.values$B`
I tried this:

```
predictions <- lapply(list1, function(x) predict(lm(A~B, data=x), new.values[new.values$name == names(x),], interval="predict"))
```

But predictions remains empty:

```
> predictions
$d1
     fit lwr upr

$d2
     fit lwr upr

$d3
     fit lwr upr
```

I guess, because R doesnt find any values for predict. If i run

```
predictions <- lapply(list1, function(x) predict(lm(A~B, data=x), new.values, interval="predict"))
```

all values in `new.values` will be used for each model.

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The names of the individual data.frames in "list1" are the column names, not the overall name of that list item. To see this, run `names(list1[[1]])`.

```
names(list1[[1]])
"name" "A"    "B"
```

If you want to loop through both the list and the list names simultaneously then `purrr::imap()` is useful.

The anonymous function will need two arguments, which I call `x` and `y`, to refer to the list and the list names, respectively.

```
library(purrr)
imap(list1, function(x, y) predict(lm(A~B, data=x), new.values[new.values$name == y,], 
                                   interval="predict")) 
$d1
       fit      lwr      upr
1 1.571429 -2.48742 5.630277

$d2
       fit      lwr      upr
2 2.214286 -1.74179 6.170362

$d3
       fit       lwr      upr
3 2.857143 -1.589103 7.303388
```

If your prediction values are also stored in a list, `purrr::map2()` would be useful for looping through two lists simultaneously.

To show this I'll `split` the "new.values" object into a list.  I can then loop through the two lists (of equal length) via `map2()`.  I use the formula notation here, where `.x` refers to the first list and `.y` to the second instead of writing an anonymous function.

```
new.val.list = split(new.values, new.values$name)
map2(list1, new.val.list, ~predict(lm(A~B, data=.x), .y, 
                                 interval="predict"))
$d1
       fit      lwr      upr
1 1.571429 -2.48742 5.630277

$d2
       fit      lwr      upr
2 2.214286 -1.74179 6.170362

$d3
       fit       lwr      upr
3 2.857143 -1.589103 7.303388
```